# How to get hold of Firestore documentRef to update an existing document?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firestore / Document DB / NoSQL, so please be patient with me on this.

I have something like below where a document is created in the "Users" collection when user sign in for the first time

```
class FirestoreService{

   private val db = Firebase.firestore
   private var userExists:Int = 0
   private var documentRef = ""

   fun addUser(user: User) {

         // check if the user exists
         db.collection("Users")
            .whereEqualTo("Email", user.email).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
               // async, so following variables will not be initialized when         
               // synchronous code is being called

             for (document in documents) {
                  documentRef = document.id
                  userExists = if(docRef!=null)  1 else 0
              }
                 
                
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.w(TAG, "Error adding User document", e)
            }

 
     if (userExists == 0){

        val userHashMap = hashMapOf(
         "name" to user.name,
         "email" to user.email,
         "notif" to false
    )
    
        db.collection("Users")
        .add(userHashMap)
        .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                 Log.d(TAG, "User document added!")
                 Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: ${documentReference.id}")

            }
         .addOnFailureListener { e ->
             Log.w(TAG, "Error adding User document", e)
         }
        }
     }


     fun updateUser(user:User){

         db.collection("Users")
            .document(documentRef)
            .set({
                "notif" to user.settings?.notifOn
            })
            .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d(TAG, "User DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!") }
            .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error updating User document", e) }

      }

}
```

Inside a fragment

```
// inside fragment method
val firestoreService = FirestoreService()
firestoreService.addUser(user);

// inside another fragment method
firestoreService.updateUser(user2)
```

As you can see I am setting variables inside `addOnSuccessListener` which is **asynchronous** so the synchronous `if` condition and `updateUser` calls do not work as expected (required values may not be assigned to the `userExists`, `documentRef` when synchrnous code being called). As I know these async behavior is handled using callbacks like mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a). But I am not sure how to make it work in my case with `addOnSuccessListener`?

Comment: What's wrong with the shared code?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have already mentioned it below below the question

Comment: @AlexMamo I update the question bit, in case my text was not clear. As an answer to your question : required values may not be assigned to the `userExists`, `documentRef` when synchronous code being called

Comment: There is no way you can use the value of `userExists` outside the onSuccess. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. And since you are using Kotlin, you might also be interested in reading this article, [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).